# SSL error with GRPC Java

Tags: security, ssl, java-8, grpc, grpc-java

JDK version : 1.8u77

proto3.0.3 version

I have tried incorporating SSL into current application. Please find below approaches we have tried.

### 1) OpenSSL Static approach

We have added the io.netty.tcnative-boringssl-static, io.netty.handler and bundles to com.pelco.vms.pelcotools.application.bnd and

Tried the below code snippet (added to RPCHandler) :

```
SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forServer(certificatePemFile, privateKeyPemFile))
                                         .sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL)
                                         .build();
server = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 8443))
                           .addService(service)
                           .sslContext(sslContext)
                           .build()
                           .start();
```

But we are receiving the below exception while building the SslContext.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.ensureAvailability(OpenSsl.java:311)
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.<init>(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:230)
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslContext.<init>(OpenSslContext.java:43)
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:347)
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:335)
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:421)
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:441)
                at com.pelco.vms.pelcotools.handlers.RPCHandler.start(RPCHandler.java:105)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:222)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:37)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:615)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:499)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:295)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:302)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:113)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:866)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:833)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:724)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:954)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.DependencyManager$SingleStaticCustomizer.addedService(DependencyManager.java:915)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1215)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdded(ServiceTracker.java:1136)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.trackAdding(ServiceTracker.java:945)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$AbstractTracked.track(ServiceTracker.java:881)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:1167)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator$ListenerInfo.serviceChanged(BundleComponentActivator.java:120)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:987)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:838)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:545)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4547)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3521)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:348)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:869)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager$3.register(AbstractComponentManager.java:857)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.RegistrationManager.changeRegistration(RegistrationManager.java:133)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.registerService(AbstractComponentManager.java:915)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:715)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:399)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:676)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialEnable(BundleComponentActivator.java:339)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:360)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$000(Activator.java:53)
                at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:260)
                at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
                at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
                at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:482)
                at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:415)
                at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
                at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:444)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:913)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:834)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:516)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4531)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2169)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)
                at aQute.launcher.Launcher.update(Launcher.java:436)
                at aQute.launcher.Launcher.activate(Launcher.java:349)
                at aQute.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:238)
                at aQute.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:87)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL not found by io.netty.handler [86]
                at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1558)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
                at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1998)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
                at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:73)
                ... 62 more
```

### 2) TLS with JDK (Jetty ALPN/NPN)

As specified in the GRPC doc (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md) tried adding the alpn-boot jar to –Xbootclasspath [JVM Arguement] and added org.eclipse.jetty.osgi to the com.pelco.vms.pelcotools.application.bnd. And tried with the below snippet:

grpc-java/SECURITY.md at master · grpc/grpc-java · GitHub
github.com
Authentication. gRPC supports a number of different mechanisms for asserting identity between an client and server. This document provides code samples demonstrating ...

```
server = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 8443))
    .addService(service)
    .useTransportSecurity(certificatePemFile, privateKeyPemFile)
    .build()
    .start();
```

The netty server is getting started but we are recieving the below expection when a client is trying to connect.

```
io.netty.channel.ChannelPipelineException: io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ServerTlsHandler.handlerAdded() has thrown an exception; removed.
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:617)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:226)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:392)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:379)
       at io.grpc.netty.NettyServerTransport.start(NettyServerTransport.java:114)
       at io.grpc.netty.NettyServer$1.initChannel(NettyServer.java:179)
       at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:113)
       at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:105)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:597)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$000(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:44)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1387)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAddedForAllHandlers(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1122)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.invokeHandlerAddedIfNeeded(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:647)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:506)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:419)
       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:478)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
       at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
       at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN$Provider
       at io.netty.handler.ssl.JettyAlpnSslEngine.newServerEngine(JettyAlpnSslEngine.java:61)
       at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator$AlpnWrapper.wrapSslEngine(JdkAlpnApplicationProtocolNegotiator.java:129)
       at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.configureAndWrapEngine(JdkSslContext.java:249)
       at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.newEngine(JdkSslContext.java:227)
       at io.grpc.netty.ProtocolNegotiators$ServerTlsHandler.handlerAdded(ProtocolNegotiators.java:146)
       at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:597)
       ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN$Provider not found by io.netty.handler [86]
       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1558)
       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1998)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       ... 27 more
```

Note : followed version as per the ALPN version table with JDK

Also tried adding the javaagent JVM option referencing the path to the Jetty alpn-agent jar. But this also reached to the above exception while connecting.

Please help to resolve the issue

Comment: This was also asked on the grpc.io mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/grpc-io/3JbJaqg1kpc/lORyrh9YBgAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `GrpcSslContexts.configure` method for creating `sslContext` in gRPC:

```
server = NettyServerBuilder.forAddress(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 8443))
                       .addService(service)
                       .sslContext(GrpcSslContexts.configure(SslContextBuilder.forServer(certificatePemFile, privateKeyPemFile)).sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL)))
                       .build()
                       .start();
```