# How to disable ssl validation operation while using Google Api Java Client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, google-api-java-client

I am using Google API Java client SDK to handle operations. I have a spring boot application contains below dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.30.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.photos.library</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-photos-library-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It is a demo application like below(Client Id, Secret, and Tokens are valid in the actual case. Also code is working at the public network. In order to test inside our network, I need to figure out SSL validation):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        AccessToken at = new AccessToken("AT", new Date());

        PhotosLibraryClient photosLibraryClient = PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(UserCredentials.newBuilder()
                                                                                                                                                                                   .setClientId("CI")
                                                                                                                                                                                   .setClientSecret("CS")
                                                                                                                                                                                   .setAccessToken(at)
                                                                                                                                                                                   .setRefreshToken("RF")
                                                                                                                                                                                   .build())).build());


        InternalPhotosLibraryClient.ListMediaItemsPagedResponse listAlbumsPagedResponse = photosLibraryClient.listMediaItems();

    }
```

But when I try to get media items from Google Photos, there will be an SSL exception below. **This SDK uses grpc**. I guess it is somehow different than rest. Because while using rest, overriding resttemplate solves SSL problems.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:982)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1138)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:957)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:748)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:492)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:467)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:700)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:399)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:500)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:65)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:592)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:508)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:632)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.photos.library.v1.internal.InternalPhotosLibraryClient.listMediaItems(InternalPhotosLibraryClient.java:676)
        at com.google.photos.library.v1.PhotosLibraryClient.listMediaItems(PhotosLibraryClient.java:211)
        at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:52)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:674)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:577)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1141)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1256)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:212)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1330)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1225)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1272)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:289)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.java:239)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:242)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:670)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 34 more
```

I want to skip verification. And used lots of different example solutions like the below links.

[SSL error with GRPC Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518160/ssl-error-with-grpc-java)

[Disable hostname verification in io.netty.handler.ssl.Sslcontext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064432/disable-hostname-verification-in-io-netty-handler-ssl-sslcontext)

[Java: Overriding function to disable SSL certificate check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723415/java-overriding-function-to-disable-ssl-certificate-check)

[Disabling certificate check in gRPC TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540899/disabling-certificate-check-in-grpc-tls)

[How to ignore PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626965/how-to-ignore-pkix-path-building-failed-sun-security-provider-certpath-suncertp)

[How to disable hostname verification in spring webclient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56184497/how-to-disable-hostname-verification-in-spring-webclient)

[Configure HostnameVerifier with reactor netty for spring-webflux WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542066/configure-hostnameverifier-with-reactor-netty-for-spring-webflux-webclient)

On the background, **it uses default OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager which also use X509TrustManagerImpl**. None of the my changes effects this hierarchy. **How to disable or change this validation?**

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @Nick code added

Comment: Why do you want to disable verification?

Comment: SSL verification causes problems in the company network while debugging. giving Keystore also did not work for my case.

Comment: Disabling hostname verification isn't supported by grpc-java. Testing use cases can use overrideAuthority() to change the hostname being verified against, sort of like what can be done via /etc/hosts. It's unclear how the company network and debugging are playing a part, but I assume they have proxies MITMing the connection. In those cases I would expect the system to be configured to trust the proxy's certificate.